# drop0 in R - meaning and usage

Tags: r, function, sparse-matrix

I am confused with use of drop0 function in r.

What does it do? Does it drop 0 values in the matrix ?

What is meant by explicit 0 ?

I have referred the description here:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/drop0.html

But, in terms of actual usage, I am not able to understand it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is exactly what it does, it drops all `0` and `FALSE` values. In the "larger example" from your source check this code `require(pryr); object_size(I.); object_size(drop0(I.))`. See also here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/sparseMatrix.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. So, if I use the drop0 in the matrix for independent variables in a regression model; that will mean that the entries which had 0 - will not be considered - correct ?

Comment: Nope. If you use `drop0` on a sparse matrix you will no longer store `0`s and `FALSE`s in memory. Please read about sparse matrices (even on Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix). You will need a huge number of coefficients to benefit from storing them in a sparse matrix.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome. I will try to make this into an answer later, just do not have time right now.